# Add Optiongroups using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript to add options to a select box using the below code,

```
function putDropDown(dataArr, fnVars){
   var dropField = document.forms[fnVars['formName']].elements[fnVars['fieldName']];
    if(dropField) {
        dropField.options.length = 0;

        if(dataArr != 'empty') {
            for(var i=0; i<dataArr[fnVars['valFld']].length; i++){
                var optIdx = dropField.options.length;
                dropField.options[optIdx] = new Option(dataArr[fnVars['txtFld']][i],dataArr[fnVars['valFld']][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now need to group the options using 'optgroup', can anyone please help me in adding the group in the above function.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: Could you please provide values of dataArr and fnVars?

Comment: That is just an array of text and value. I can pass the option group label along with the dataArr, but can you please tell me how to add optgroup like dropField.options[optIdx] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correctly understand you...

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="mainForm">
        <select id="mainSelect" name="mainSelect"></select>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
function putDropDown(dataArr, fnVars){
    var dropField = document.forms[fnVars['formName']].elements[fnVars['fieldName']];
    if (dropField) {
        dropField.options.length = 0;
        if (dataArr != 'empty') {
            for (var i in dataArr[fnVars['valFld']]) {
                var groupData = dataArr[fnVars['valFld']][i];
                var group = document.createElement('optgroup');
                group.label = groupData.group;
                for (var key in groupData.options) {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = key;
                    opt.innerHTML = groupData.options[key];
                    group.appendChild(opt);
                }
                dropField.appendChild(group);
            }
        }
    }
}
putDropDown(
    {mSelect: [
        {group: 'top', options: {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}},
        {group: 'bottom', options: {f: 'foo', b: 'bar'}}
    ]},
    {formName: 'mainForm', fieldName: 'mainSelect', valFld: 'mSelect'}
);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The example which you have given is correct, but this will create options right? I wanted help in creating option groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @NehaDangui NP, hope it helps you!)